# jQuery Accordion: links don't work

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm working on a page using jQuery's [accordion UI element](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion). I modeled my HTML on that example, except that inside the `<li>` elements, I have some unordered lists of links. Like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".ui-accordion-container").accordion(
        {active: "a.default", alwaysOpen: true, autoHeight: false}
     );
  });

  <ul class="ui-accordion-container">
  <li> <!-- Start accordion section -->
   <a href='#' class="accordion-label">A Group of Links</a>
   <ul class="linklist">
      <li><a href="http://example.com">Example Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://example.com">Example Link</a></li>
   </ul>

   <!--and of course there's another group -->
```

### Problem: Links don't work

In all browsers I've tested, the links in those accordion menus cause **the accordion section to collapse** instead of taking you to the linked page. (I can still right-click and go to the linked site.)

Could this be some kind of click binding issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, the accordian widget sets all the links to headers. To change it, you need to specify a selector with the `headers` option. So, your code would look like this:

```
$(".ui-accordion-container").accordion(
   { active: "a.default", ...,  header: "a.accordion-label" }
);
```

Comment: Have been looking for this answer for a while! Note however, that this chunk of code may be in the bootstrap.js, in case you're looking for it, and not in the accordion.js file.

Comment: @Matthew Crumley this answer is working for me, but I have $(...).accordion is not a function warning in console. Any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 8):

Try adding an inline onlick that prevents event bubbling:

```
...
<a href='#' onclick="event.stopPropagation()" class="accordion-label">A Group of Links</a>
...
```

Or a domready event like so:

```
$(".toggle-title a").click(function(event){ event.stopPropagation()})
```

However the latter didn't work for me even though code wise it makes sense, jQuery executes the click! Anyone that can explain that to me feel free, I come from MooTools and Google Closure background which has addEvent functions.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me (maybe because I have a nested accordion). And I was indeed able to use the domready event.

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same problem and could not find an answer anywhere. In fact, a couple sources said it just couldn't be done.

Upon further playing, I did find a working solution. May not be great, but it works like a charm.

First, just make sure the links you want to be clickable, and immune to the accordion controls, is easily identifiable. I had a class on mine.

```
 $('.stats a').click(function(){
expander.accordion('disable');
window.open($(this).attr('href'));

setTimeout ( function() {
  expander.accordion('enable');
}, 250 );
```

});

Essentially, this listens for when a link inside the accordion header is clicked. When it is, the accordion is temporarily disabled, keeping it from firing as normal. The link is then opened, in this case, in a new window but you could use document.location as well

If we re-enabled the accordion immediately, it will still fire and toggle the accordion. I found that a super-short timeout provides enough delay.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

here is a really simple solution

http://www.designerstalk.com/forums/help-me/41297-jquery-accordion-embedding-links-help-needed.html

Answer (score 0):

AlwaysOpen should be true.

Answer (score 0):

May be my suggestion is not using accordion() function, [ which i didn't know about before, Thank you for bring it up :) ] but still show how to have have an Accordion UI Element.

**HTML**

```
<body id="body">
    <h2>Accordian</h2>
        <div id="accordion" class="">

                <div class="toggle_all">
                        <ul class="links">
                                <li><a class="openall" href="#"><span>Open All</span></a></li>
                                <li>|</li>
                                <li><a class="closeall" href="#"><span>Close All</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>

                <!-- toggleAll ends -->
                <div class="accordion">
                        <div class="section_title_accordion design-gray">
                                <h3><a href="#" class="open"><span>Lorem ipsum</span></a></h3>
                        </div>
                        <!-- section_title_accordion ends -->
                        <div class="accordion_content"> <span class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span> </div>

                        <!-- accordion_content ends -->
                </div>
                <!-- accordion ends -->
                <div class="accordion">
                        <div class="section_title_accordion design-gray">
                                <h3><a href="#" class="open"><span>Lorem ipsum</span></a></h3>
                        </div>
                        <!-- section_title_accordion ends -->

                        <div class="accordion_content"> <span class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span> </div>
                        <!-- accordion_content ends -->
                </div>
                <!-- accordion ends -->
                <div class="accordion">
                        <div class="section_title_accordion design-gray">
                                <h3><a href="#" class="open"><span>Lorem ipsum</span></a></h3>

                        </div>
                        <!-- section_title_accordion ends -->
                        <div class="accordion_content"> <span class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span> </div>
                        <!-- accordion_content ends -->
                </div>
                <!-- accordion ends -->
        </div>

        <!-- #accordion ends -->
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css" >
#body { margin-left:20%; font:12px verdana; }
.accordion { width:500px; }
h3 { margin:0; padding:0; }
.section_title_accordion { float:left; width:500px; margin:2px 0 0; }
.section_title_accordion h3 span { margin:0; float:left; color:#fff; padding:2px 0 3px 10px; }
.section_title_accordion a span { padding-left:20px; }
.accordion_content { border-bottom:1px solid #666666; border-left:1px solid #666666; border-right:1px solid #666666; float:left; padding:5px 3px; }
.accordion_content span.content { margin:5px 0 0; }
.design-gray { background:#003366; }
.design-gray a { color:#fff; float:left; width:100%; height:22px; background:#003366; text-decoration:none; }
.design-gray a:hover { text-decoration:underline;}
.on .design-gray a { color:#fff; float:left; width:100%; height:22px; background:#003366;}
.accordion_content_hover { background:#ffffcc; color:#000099; }
.toggle_all { padding:20px 0; width:500px; margin-bottom:5px; }
.toggle_all ul { padding:0; margin:0; }
.toggle_all ul li { list-style-type:none; }
.toggle_all .links li { float:left; padding-left:5px; }
.toggle_all .links li a, .toggleAll .links span { color:#666666; }
</style>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".accordion_content").hide();
  $("a.open").click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".accordion").find(".accordion_content").toggle();
        $(this).parents(".accordion").toggleClass('on');    
        return false;
  });   

    $(".accordion_content").mouseover(function() {
            $(this).addClass('accordion_content_hover');
            return false;       
    });

    $(".accordion_content").mouseout(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('accordion_content_hover');
            return false;       
    });

    $("a.openall").click(function() {
        $(".accordion_content").show();
        $(this).parents("#accordion").find(".accordion").addClass('on');
        return false;
    });
    $("a.closeall").click(function() {
          $(".accordion_content").hide();
          $(this).parents("#accordion").find(".accordion").removeClass('on');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

As my answer to your other question says:

```
 navigation: true
```

Should be set in your option list.

Comment: This didn't help me. The documentation says "If set, looks for the anchor that matches location.href and activates it."