# How to make a "recursive" accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion

I found this code on here from this post:
[jQuery Accordion: links don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332384/jquery-accordion-links-dont-work)

and it is almost what I need. But what I want is so when you click on one of the tabs instead of showing text it brings up another set of tabs that you can click on and then the same thing happens when you click one of those tabs, etc.

I tried developing this myself using ajax but I got nowhere so I decided to try here.

You can see the full code here:
http://mywoundsolutions.com/accordian.html

Thanks for the help.

Comment: In order to make a recursive accordion, you must first make a recursive accordion... Seriously, though, I don't see any attempt towards nesting your accordions in the link given, it's just a plain one-level accordion.  What have you tried, and why didn't it work?

Comment: I did try but i took it out because it did not work

Comment: I tried nesting the accordion div where the text was but that did not work properly. I could post this online so you can see it if you'd like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [jQuery menu](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/) system... it's an iPod-like menu that looks pretty good. Check out the examples on that page

Answer (score 0):

Would something like [this example](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ddaccordionmenu-glossy.htm) be a starting point?

The submenu displays inline, so there's no need to mouse sideways and risk losing a flyout submenu.