# jQuery accordion making some page links disabled

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I'm using jQuery accordion which expands and collapses fine but when it expands it hides some of the page tabs and links. When it collapses these tabs and links don't work, they just become disabled. Can somebody help me? What could be the problem?

Here is the link where the problem exist http://www.alpolink.com. Five tabs in the header will work fine until you click on the vertical accordion menu, the last most right tab and right most links on the page don't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332384/jquery-accordion-links-dont-work

Answer (score 0):

Feels like you are overwriting some objects. Maybe you have a problem how you select your elements. Like $('.class').bla() will change all objects with this class. You might want to check those selectors you use. Make sure they only select the objects you really want.