# Jquery UI Accordion - Collapsed & Clickable Links

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am attempting to use the Jquery UI accordion as a Side Navigation option. The problem is I am unable to have the accordion totally collapsed on load (and when desired by user) and to have active links on some of the pannel headers.

**Using**
Jquery 1.6.2 & 
Jquery UI 1.8.16.

```
$(function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true,
    autoHeight: false,
});
});

<div id="accordion">
<h3><a href="http://link1.html">Outside Link 1</a></h3>
<div></div>
<h3><a href="http://link2.html">Outside Link 2</a></h3>
<div></div>
<h3><a href="http://link3.html">Outside Link 3</a></h3>
<div></div>

<h3><a href="#">More Info</a></h3>
<div class="subNav">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="pageLink1.html">Another Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="pageLink2.html">Another Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="pageLink3.html">Another Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

     <h3><a href="http://link4.html">Outside Link 4</a></h3>
<div></div>

<h3><a href="#">More Info 2</a></h3>
<div class="subNav">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="pageLink4.html">Another Page 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="pageLink5.html">Another Page 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="pageLink6.html">Another Page 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
   ...etc
   </div>
```

"Outside Links" should link to other pages directly. "More Info & More Info 2" should open up so the user can choose "Another Page" respectively.

I am not able to collapse the accordion on load or if clicked if I change the header selector (I can access the "Outside Links" this way). Could my empty divs be the culprit?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It does work for me, except accordion isn't going to work the way you want it to (with the outside links). You may just have to manually create something instead. I don't know how many sub links you will have, but maybe just create a toggle to open and close independently.

Comment: check this links [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332384/jquery-accordion-links-dont-work]

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck. someone made a plugin for this.

http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/jquery-accordion-3/# It works like you want it to.

Comment: The plugin seems to work like I was hoping. I think Option #4 is what I will attempt to retrofit. Thanks for the help!