# Embed links to other page in jQuery accordion header

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a standard jQuery UI accordion, and I am trying to embed a link in the accordion header (bit that doesn't collapse, h3 in my code) that goes to a different page rather than expand the accordion. However, when I click on the link 'LINK TO OTHER PAGE', it just expands the accordion. This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();

        $("#accordionID1").accordion({
            autoHeight: false,
            active: false,
            collapsible: true,
            header: 'h3',
            active: "a.default"
        });
}); 
</script>


<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs1">Title 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs2">Title 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs3">Title 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs4">Title 4</a></li>
    </ul>


    <div id="tabs1">
        <div id="accordionID1" class="accordionClass">
            <h3>
                <table class="tableClass1">
                    <tr class="rowhead">
                        <td class="class1">Some text 1</td>
                        <td class="class1">Some text 2</td>
                        <td class="class1">Some text 3
                            <a class="default">LINK TO OTHER PAGE</a> and some more.
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </h3>
            <div>
            <!-- start share class table -->
                <table class="tableClass2">
                    <tr class="rowhead">
                        <th class="class2">Heading 1</th>
                        <th class="class2">Heading 2</th>
                        <th class="class2">Heading 3</th>
                        <th class="class2">Heading 4</th>
                        <th class="class2">Heading 5</th>
                        <th class="class2">Heading 6</th>
                    </tr>

                 </table> 
            </div>
        </div> <!-- accordionID1 -->
    </div> <!-- tabs1 -->

    <!-- repeat for id=tabs2 -->
    <!-- repeat for id=tabs3 -->
    <!-- repeat for id=tabs4 -->

</div> <!-- tabs -->
```

I've have essentially followed the tip [jQuery Accordion: links don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332384/jquery-accordion-links-dont-work), which has led to the code above.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
C

Comment: Issue #1, you're using tables for non-tabular data. Issue #2, `<h3>` elements may not have `<table>` descendants.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've changed the enclosing <h3> to <div class="accHeader">; and exchanged header: 'h3' for header: 'div.accHeader'.

Comment: Sorry... I timed out. I've changed the markup to accHeader as above, but my links still don't work. Any further ideas?

Comment: those issues weren't to fix your accordion. They were to fix your markup. The selector used for `header` cannot have a clickable descendant.You'd need to select the first two `.class1` elements, but rather than hammering bad markup with javascript, I'd recommend starting over and using semantic markup.

Comment: I completely accept I shouldn't have used the `<h3>` tag. I started from the example code  found here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ and didn't remove it. However, the content of what was my `<h3>` tag before I changed it to `<div class="accHeader">` really is tabular, as in I'm not using the table for layout. Again, maybe not obvious from the simple example I have given, I was just trying to keep the code easy to digest.

Anyway, if it's not possible to have a clickable descendent of the header then I guess I'm on a hiding to nothing.